# My transaction keeps reverting even though i have funded it with more than enough eth. I am running it on a persistent ganache network with brownie

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, web3py, brownie

My enter lottery function which charges 5 dollars won't transact successfully when I deploy it with brownie. It works fine on remix, but when i try making a script file to run it it keeps sending the error

```
 ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: VM Exception while processing 
 transaction: revert'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you 
 must set the gas limit manually.
```

At first I tried creating a separate script file to run it but it send that error.I tried running it in my deploy script but it still doesn't work.

My deploy script

```
        from brownie import lottery, accounts, config, network, 
        MockV3Aggregator, LinkToken, VRFCoordinatorMock
        from scripts.helpful import get_account, deploy_mocks, 
        LOCAL
        from web3 import Web3

        value = Web3.toWei(0.04, "ether")

            
        def deploy_txn():
            account = get_account()
            print(f"owner is {account}")
            print(f"{network.show_active()} is the current network")
            if network.show_active() not in LOCAL:
                pfaddress = config[network.show_active()]["padress"] 
                vrf = config[network.show_active()]["vrf"]
                link = config[network.show_active()]["link_token"]
                keyhash = config[network.show_active()]["keyhash"]
                fee = config[network.show_active()]["fee"]
            else:
                deploy_mocks()
                pfaddress = MockV3Aggregator[-1].address
                vrf = VRFCoordinatorMock[-1].address
                link = LinkToken[-1].address
                keyhash = '0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311'
                fee = '100000000000000000'

            caddr = lottery.deploy(vrf, pfaddress, link, keyhash, fee, {"from": account})
            print(caddr)

        def start_lottery():
            account = get_account()
            lottery[-1].startLottery({"from": account})


        def enter_lottery():
            account = get_account()
            lottery[-1].enter({"from": account, "value": value})

        def main():
            deploy_txn()
            start_lottery()
            enter_lottery()
```

My solidity enterLottery function

```
   function enter() payable public {
        require(ETHtoUSD(msg.value) >= usdfee, "Not enough ETH!");
        require(currentstate == lotteryState.open, "Lottery isn't open yet!");
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
     }
```

the usdfee is $5 and I funded it with 0.04ETH($64)

Comment: do you get the error when you call the `enter`?

Comment: Yes, along with any other function that I have to define the value i'm paying(payable functions)

Comment: will this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194882/execution-reverted-during-call-this-transaction-will-likely-revert-if-you-wish